# Is this the correct way to enforce a specific Spring version using the enforcer plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I wish to enforce a specific Spring version (3.1.2) using the [maven-enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html)'s **[bannedDependencies](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html)** rule.

Is this the correct way to configure the enforcer plugin to achieve that ?

```
<configuration>
    <rules>
        <bannedDependencies>
            <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.springframework</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <includes>
                <include>org.springframework:*:3.1.2</include>
            </includes>
        </bannedDependencies>
    </rules>
    <fail>true</fail>
    <failFast>true</failFast>
    <ignoreCache>true</ignoreCache>
</configuration>
```

The above seems to work and doing a `mvn enforcer:enforce` on the command line highlighted that v3.1.0 or org.springframework:spring-oxm was being pulled in as a transitive dependency.

It also seems like one might want to use **[dependencyConvergence](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html)** rule, but it highlights a lot of dependency errors which are excluded automatically as 'conflicts' by maven.

Here is a snippet with a bit more context :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.enforcer.plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-versions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <bannedDependencies>
                                <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.springframework</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.springframework.security</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org.springframework:*:${spring.version}</include>
                                    <include>org.springframework.security:*:${spring-security.version}</include>
                                    <include>org.slf4j:*:${slf4j.version}</include>
                                </includes>
                            </bannedDependencies>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <version>${enforce.jdk.version}</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                        <failFast>true</failFast>
                        <ignoreCache>true</ignoreCache>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
 .....
</plugins>
```

Comment: I don't really know what you expect to hear? If it works for you then I guess it's fine. I don't think that there is any wrongs or rights with your usage.

Comment: I guess the point of the question is that you have to both *exclude* and *include* the spring jars - is there anything cleaner like *restrict-to-version* or something that would make this less verbose and error-prone (DRY)? Or perhaps this is the wrong plugin, and such problems should be solved by the versions plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bannedDependencies` snippet in the question above does not work because of the fact that the `<include>` tag does not understand the `groupId:artifactId:version:type` notation. Thus, wildcard cannot be used to replace whole sections to convey `include all versions of ALL artifacts in a group`.

However, by using the maven [Dependency Version Range](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges) it is possible to enforce a specific dependency.

Given the following versions of a given artifact (in the order that they were released):

`3.0.0` , `3.0.1` , `3.1.0`, `3.2.0.RELEASE`, `3.3.0`

let's say we want to tell the enforcer plugin to exclude everything but `3.2.0.RELEASE` then the only way to do that is :

`exclude versions X  where  X < DESIRED_VERSION  OR X > DESIRED VERSION`

The above would effectively mean :
`exclude all versions X where X != DESIRED_VERSION`

Since the maven dependency version notation does not permit a 'Not Version' notation, we have to make do with using the less than and greater than notations in combination like so:

`(,3.2.0.RELEASE),(3.2.0.RELEASE,)`

which means:    `version < '3.2.0.RELEASE'  or version > '3.2.0.RELEASE'`.

Finally, a snippet of what works is as follows:

```
<bannedDependencies>
    <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>org.springframework:*:(,${spring.version}),(${spring.version},)</exclude>    
    </excludes>
</bannedDependencies>
```